# Masonry alternative for Angular 2+

Tags: angular, masonry, angular-masonry

I'm working with `angular2-masonry` in a project with the latest Angular version (v5.1.3) I have being looking for Masonry and other alternatives to implement in my aplication. I tried multiple ones and I didn't like the implementation. I tried doing a native CSS masonry but I need to order the content from left to right.

So, the question is, there is an alternative well integrated in Angular to Masonry? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I have done it! I have implemented a solution based on the solution given by [Andy Barefoot](https://codepen.io/andybarefoot/), can be checked [in this CodePen](https://codepen.io/andybarefoot/pen/RLRPQL). I have created [a Gist](https://gist.github.com/urkopineda/026023d70d1d1745297515abb145d5f3) showing how I implemented it in my Angular app. The trick is in the CSS and JS:

[image]

**CSS:**

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px,1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 20px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
function resizeGridItem(item){
  grid = document.getElementsByClassName("grid")[0];
  rowHeight = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(grid).getPropertyValue('grid-auto-rows'));
  rowGap = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(grid).getPropertyValue('grid-row-gap'));
  rowSpan = Math.ceil((item.querySelector('.content').getBoundingClientRect().height+rowGap)/(rowHeight+rowGap));
    item.style.gridRowEnd = "span "+rowSpan;
}

function resizeAllGridItems(){
  allItems = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
  for(x=0;x<allItems.length;x++){
    resizeGridItem(allItems[x]);
  }
}

function resizeInstance(instance){
    item = instance.elements[0];
  resizeGridItem(item);
}

window.onload = resizeAllGridItems();
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeAllGridItems);

allItems = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
for(x=0;x<allItems.length;x++){
  imagesLoaded( allItems[x], resizeInstance);
}
```